# Postgresql - how to use bool_and with group by

Tags: postgresql, group-by, aggregate

I have the following schema, that represent collection of messages, where each message can have multiple items (at least 1). Every item belongs to a message. Items can change over time.

```
CREATE TABLE messages (
    message_id int8 NOT NULL,
    -- some more fields here...
    CONSTRAINT messages_pk PRIMARY KEY (message_id)
);

CREATE TABLE items (
    item_id int8 NOT NULL,
    message_id int8 NOT NULL,
    last_update_time timestamptz NOT NULL,
    -- some more fields...
    CONSTRAINT items_pk PRIMARY KEY (item_id)
);
ALTER TABLE items ADD CONSTRAINT item_message_fk FOREIGN KEY (message_id) REFERENCES messages(message_id);
```

The user can read the items, so I have a table to represent which messages where read and when.

```
CREATE TABLE read_items (
    item_id int8 NOT NULL,
    last_read_at timestamptz NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT read_items_pk PRIMARY KEY (item_id)
);
ALTER TABLE read_items ADD CONSTRAINT read_items_fk FOREIGN KEY (item_id) REFERENCES items(item_id);
```

Since items can change, if a user has read the item and after that it was changed, I want it to be marked as non-read.
So, to see if an item was read or not, I have this query:

```
select items.item_id, ...
        case when read_items.last_read_at is null 
            or items.last_update_time > read_items.last_read_at 
        then false else true end
        as is_read
from items
    left outer join read_items
        on items.item_id = read_items.item_id;
```

A message is defined read if all its items were read. I'm looking for a way to get the "read status" of all the messages.
I thought to use something like the following query, but it fails:

```
select 
    messages.message_id, ...
    bool_and(case when read_items.last_read_at is null 
                or items.last_update_time > read_items.last_read_at 
            then false else true end) 
       as is_read
from messages 
    join items on messages.message_id = items.message_id 
        left outer join read_items on items.item_id = read_items.item_id 
group by 
    messages.message_id;
```

The error message I get is `SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near "bool_and"` .

Is there a way to achieve what I'm trying without a sub query?
If not, does using a sub query affects performance?

Thanks!

Comment: The syntax [works for me](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=c0838f09e127b4c3af55625f44f9b609). You probably have some other error in the `...` part you didn't show us.

Comment: Note that you can simplify your expression to `bool_and(read_items.last_read_at is null or items.last_update_time > read_items.last_read_at)` no CASE expression needed

Comment: Works indeed! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As @a_horse_with_no_name indicated in their comment, the syntax is correct. The query failed for me due to some issues with the client I used.